# problem in getting particular item from database in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to show data from database.I have created the database and now i am showing the database in the listview.Below is the crash that i am unable to resolve

09-08 01:20:45.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16459): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 114 requested, with a size of 114
09-08 01:20:45.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16459):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
09-08 01:20:45.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16459):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
09-08 01:20:45.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16459):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
09-08 01:20:45.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16459):     at com.redorange.database.MessageDbAdapter.GetSeedDetails(MessageDbAdapter.java:360)
09-08 01:20:45.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16459):     at com.redorange.headshop.CustomAdapter.onCreate(CustomAdapter.java:36)
09-08 01:20:45.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16459):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-08 01:20:45.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16459):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
09-08 01:20:45.651: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16459):     ... 11 more

Can anyone help me,,,

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `GetSeedDetails` method use something like this code:

```
public ArrayList<GetDataBaseValues> GetSeedDetails()throws SQLException
{
    ArrayList<GetDataBaseValues> seedRecordsList = new  ArrayList<GetDataBaseValues>();
    GetDataBaseValues getDatabaseVariables;
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query("headshop", 
            new String[] {"_id","name","grade","description"
            }, null, null, null, null, null);

    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    while(mCursor.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
        getDatabaseVariables = new GetDataBaseValues();
        String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        getDatabaseVariables.setName(name);
        String grade = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("grade"));
        getDatabaseVariables.setGrade(grade);
        String desc = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("description"));
        getDatabaseVariables.setDesc(desc);
        seedRecordsList.add(getDatabaseVariables);
        mCursor.moveToNext();
    }
    mCursor.close();
    return seedRecordsList;
}
```

Comment: ,,,,its crashing when i am giving same value that is 0 to getstring,,,,hows to solve this problem ?

Comment: I think it's because in `0` index is `_id` column which type is `int`. If you want get it value, use `int id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));`, also updated answer, you can see how to get other columns. This columns names are names of your table columns.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to access an item from your database at a position that isn't valid

`android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 114`

You're probably trying to access an item that doesn't exist within the dataset, either a row beyond the end of the returned rows or else an item within the row that doesn't exist.

Show us your CustomAdapter code (with line numbers if possible!)

### EDIT

Your function GetSeedDetails is wrong. You're moving logic is incorrect causing you to exceed the limits of the cursor. Use only the moveToNext call in the while condition and you'll iterate over the data values. Also dont forget to close the cursor when you're done!

```
public ArrayList<GetDataBaseValues> GetSeedDetails()throws SQLException
{
    ArrayList<GetDataBaseValues> seedRecordsList = new  ArrayList<GetDataBaseValues>();
    GetDataBaseValues getDatabaseVariables; 
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query("headshop", new String[] {"_id","name","grade","description"
              }, null, null, null, null, null);


    while(mCursor.moveToNext())
    {  
         getDatabaseVariables = new GetDataBaseValues();
         getDatabaseVariables.setName(mCursor.getString(01).toString());
         Log.e("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", mCursor.getString(1).toString());
         getDatabaseVariables.setGrade(mCursor.getString(0).toString());
         Log.e("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", mCursor.getString(2).toString());
         getDatabaseVariables.setDesc(mCursor.getString(0).toString());
         Log.e("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", mCursor.getString(3).toString());
         seedRecordsList.add(getDatabaseVariables);

  }
  mCursor.close();
  return seedRecordsList;
}
```

Comment: here is the code,,,,,                                                  http://pastebin.com/pPYPCr1A

Comment: @user813953, I think problem in `mDb.GetSeedDetails()` method. can you show code of it?

Comment: @user813953: Updated my answer. This should stop that crash

Comment: @kurru thanks,,,very much,,,,, i think my error was i was not closing the cursor,,am i right,,??

Comment: @user813953: Another fix to the text, got my approaches mixed up :P

Comment: @user813953: You're problem was 3 fold. You're while condition doesn't ever end, since the cursor doesnt == null when its out of entries. Even if it did, you were attempting to move to the next item whenever you were on the final entry, causing your out of bounds exception. and while minor, not closing the cursor is bad!

Comment: its crashing when i am giving same value that is 0 to getstring,,,,hows to solve this problem ? –

Comment: well 0 is "_id", 1 is "name", 2 is "grade", 3 is "description". If you make another question with this problem it would be good. Or post updated code example and updated error message?